# How to load balance and redirect with haproxy

Tags: redirect, load-balancing, haproxy

Content on both servers are located in http://localhost:88/web/portal
I have configured haproxy with the following config block

```
listen webfarm 0.0.0.0:8080
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server webserver01 192.168.1.10:88 check
    server webserver02 192.168.1.20:88 check
```

How would I get haproxy to redirect further into directories? I was trying to do redirects locally via apache but all I am getting is loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but something like this may be what you are looking for:

```
frontend my_frontend
    mode http
    bind *:8080
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    default_backend my_backend

backend my_backend
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor

    reqrep ^(.*)     /web/portal\1

    server webserver01 192.168.1.10:88 check
    server webserver02 192.168.1.20:88 check
```

The key change is the [reqrep](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-reqrep) line which takes in the requested uri and prepends `/web/portal` to it (at least it should).

Sorry it is not in the same format as your example but I just copied it from some of my config and changed it. Let me know if that works for your situation.